# ffmpeg livestream alway stop after 160hours streamming

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, live-streaming

I use ffmpeg with this code to run stream youtube 24/7 from Windows VPS. But stream alway stop after 160-167 hours and I don't know why.

```
   dir/b/s "C:\Users\NASA\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\1\*.mp4" > list.txt
:encode video
:loop
for /F "delims=;" %%F in (list.txt)  DO ffmpeg -re -i "%%F" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 3368k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 198k -ar 44100 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -f flv -s 1280x720 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
goto loop
```

And this is stream log. I google " ***Larger timestamp than 24-bit: 0xffffff9f***" but nothing about this error. I contacted to admin server system, he comfirmed that has no issue connection. Then I tried again in Windows 7 and Windows server 2012, same result, still drop after 160h on youtube.

```
    Larger timestamp than 24-bit: 0xffffff9f
[flv @ 000000000275c820] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 000000000275c820] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=10575 fps= 30 q=-1.0 Lsize=   88449kB time=00:05:52.52 bitrate=2055.4kbits
/s speed=0.998x
video:79769kB audio:8263kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB mux
ing overhead: 0.474711%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] frame I:182   Avg QP:20.08  size: 41314
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] frame P:4955  Avg QP:22.97  size: 11557
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] frame B:5438  Avg QP:23.75  size:  3108
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] consecutive B-frames: 29.6%  3.9%  5.0% 61.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] mb I  I16..4: 23.0% 49.4% 27.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] mb P  I16..4: 10.8% 15.7%  3.3%  P16..4: 17.4%  6.3
%  2.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:44.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] mb B  I16..4:  1.7%  1.6%  0.2%  B16..8: 12.4%  3.4
%  0.3%  direct: 4.9%  skip:75.4%  L0:46.3% L1:46.0% BI: 7.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] 8x8 transform intra:51.7% inter:36.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 38.7% 59.1% 14.8% inter: 4
.5% 13.5% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] i16 v,h,dc,p: 43% 36% 17%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 31% 21%  2%  2%
 3%  3%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 29% 15%  4%  5%
 5%  5%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] i8c dc,h,v,p: 41% 27% 27%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.1% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000002760560] kb/s:1853.78

C:\Users\NASA\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -re -i "C:\Users\NASA\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin
\1\6 x24.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 2500k -bufsize
3368k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 198k -ar 44100 -metadat
a title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -met
adata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -meta
data encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata perfor
mer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -
metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -f flv -s 1280x72
0 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
ffmpeg version N-87353-g183fd30 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --e
nable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --
enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv
--enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-li
bfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug -
-enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enabl
e-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li
bsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolam
e --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
 --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable
-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enab
le-zlib
  libavutil      55. 76.100 / 55. 76.100
  libavcodec     57.106.101 / 57.106.101
  libavformat    57. 82.101 / 57. 82.101
  libavdevice    57.  8.101 / 57.  8.101
  libavfilter     6.105.100 /  6.105.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\NASA\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\1\6 x.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-10-16T20:51:09.000000Z
  Duration: 00:03:22.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1300 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709)
, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1105 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (def
ault)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-10-16T20:51:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 00000000029d0020] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000000029d0020] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 00000000029d0020] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 00000000029d0020] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decim
ate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_a
dapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=60 keyint_min=6 s
cenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 q
pmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=2500 vbv_bufsize=3368 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=n
one filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
frame=   14 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kb
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf57.82.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(pro
gressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default
)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.106.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 2500000/0/0 buffer size: 3368000 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz,
 stereo, fltp, 198 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-10-16T20:51:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
      encoder         : Lavc57.106.101 libmp3lame
frame=   29 fps= 28 q=29.0 size=      77kB time=00:00:00.41 bitrate=1498.7kbits/
frame=   44 fps= 28 q=29.0 size=     129kB time=00:00:00.94 bitrate=1118.8kbits/
frame=   60 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=     180kB time=00:00:01.88 bitrate= 781.8kbits/
frame=   76 fps= 30 q=26.0 size=     220kB time=00:00:02.37 bitrate= 758.1kbits/
frame=   91 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=     311kB time=00:00:02.84 bitrate= 895.3kbits/
frame=  107 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     356kB time=00:00:03.34 bitrate= 870.9kbits/
frame=  122 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     395kB time=00:00:03.84 bitrate= 843.3kbits/
frame=  137 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     428kB time=00:00:04.31 bitrate= 813.2kbits/
frame=  153 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     535kB time=00:00:04.80 bitrate= 911.9kbits/
frame=  168 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     598kB time=00:00:05.30 bitrate= 923.0kbits/
frame=  184 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     661kB time=00:00:05.77 bitrate= 938.2kbits/
frame=  199 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     757kB time=00:00:06.27 bitrate= 989.2kbits/
frame=  215 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     833kB time=00:00:06.76 bitrate=1008.2kbits/
frame=  230 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     893kB time=00:00:07.23 bitrate=1011.1kbits/
frame=  246 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     963kB time=00:00:07.73 bitrate=1019.8kbits/
frame=  261 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1049kB time=00:00:08.23 bitrate=1043.7kbits/
frame=  276 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1117kB time=00:00:08.70 bitrate=1052.2kbits/
frame=  292 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1166kB time=00:00:09.19 bitrate=1038.3kbits/
frame=  307 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1216kB time=00:00:09.69 bitrate=1027.8kbits/
frame=  322 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1304kB time=00:00:10.18 bitrate=1048.4kbits/
frame=  338 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1363kB time=00:00:11.15 bitrate=1000.8kbits/
s speed=0.985x
```